# Metatag replacement in client side

Tags: javascript, html

I have requirement where i need replace the Meta Tags on client side based on some user selection. For that what i have tried is i have meta content with in the DIV Tag. On Java script i am planning to replace. Div and innerhtml My Meta taga are placed with the Head tag. Using the DIV tag i am not able to put the meta tags dynimically. I am able to place all other type of content except Meta tag.

I would like to know is there any limitation what we can place and what we can not place in DIV tag.

Comment: What are you going to use the meta tag's dynamic content for? It won't be useful in SEO, for example.

Comment: As part of my testing, i am writting a automated script to replace meta tags. The meta tags are used in my Web anylitics. That way i can simulate differnt type of users. Because all my user information is placed with in meta data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery** to select and replace metatags in the header:

```
$('meta').attr('charset');
```

This would return the charset such as "UTF-8".

To replace it with something else, you can use.

```
$('meta').attr('charset','somethingelse');
```

Likewise

```
$('meta').attr('author','ctrl-alt-dileep');
```

If you don't want to user jQuery try https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName